# Passing id params to backend MySQL results in undefined value

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i've been developing a blog website, and now, putting the comments system. The comments sends to a backend mysql, with an ID as a foreign key of the corresponding blog Id. The ID is extracted of the useParam hook, when i click to a blog, the url changes to the blog ID, and the commens system use that param to send it, with name and the comment, to the backend.
This is managed by a POST request, that works perfectly when i try to do this with the vs code extension thunder client. But when i do with the web, pass to the backend, the name, comment, but the id, sets undefined.
The useParams hook works perfectly, console.log shows the ID, but pass undefined to the backend.
Here some proofs:
[thunder client post request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xvazt.png)

[pass name, comment, but id undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zqggc.png)

Here is my Fullpost code, that shows the particular blog:

```
function Fullpost() {
  var { id } = useParams();

  const [name, setName] = useState('')
  const [comment, setComment] = useState('')

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    await createCommentRequest(targeted)
  }
  const targeted = {id: id, name: name, comment: comment}

  return (
    <>
        {blogs.filter(e => e.id == id).map(e => (
            <div className="blogs">
                <h1>{e.post}</h1>
                <h2>{e.name}</h2>
                <p><small>{e.createAt}</small></p>
            </div>
        ))}
        <hr />
        <form className="comment" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <input type="text" placeholder="nombre..." onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}/>
          <input type="text" placeholder="comenta..." onChange={(e) => setComment(e.target.value)}/>
          <button type="submit">comentar</button>
        </form>
    </>
  )
}
```

The createCommentRequest():

```
import axios from 'axios'

export const createCommentRequest = async (comment, id) => {
    await axios.post(`http://localhost:4000/blogs/${id}`, comment)
}
```

The create comment function:

```
export const addComment = async(req, res) => {
    const {name, comment} = req.body
    const [result] = await pool.query(`INSERT INTO comments (id, name, comment) VALUES (?, ?, ?)`,[
        req.params.id, name, comment
    ])
    return res.json({
        id: result.insertId, name, comment,
    })
    console.log(result)
    res.send('creando comentario')
}
```

Any response will be received

Comment: ```await createCommentRequest(targeted)``` you are not passing id to that function. That function expects two params: comment and id. You are passing an object in a first param

Comment: It works, how i've not noticed, thanks man!